# XtraGridView - Where com variavel

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Galera boa noite, como vai?

Estou criando uma tela de cadastro de usuário, onde todo usuário tem uma ID, nesta tela, tenho um xtragridview, que carrega algumas informações de endereços.

Porem, nesta tabela do xtragridview, tem endereços de vários outros clientes, então precisava que ele só trouxesse os endereços desse cliente.

Estou tentando criar um query, no datasource do gridview:

```
select "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."id_cliente_cobranca",
   "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."endereco",
   "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."numero",
   "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."bairro",
   "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."cidade",
   "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."estado",
   "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."cep"
from "dbo"."Cliente_enderecos_alter" "Cliente_enderecos_alter"

where  "Cliente_enderecos_alter"."id_cliente" = @id_cliente
```

Aí que vem minha duvida, como que defino esse parâmetro `@id_cliente`?

se fosse uma consulta normal, faria assim:

```
 consql._sql = @"SELECT * FROM Login WHERE id_usu = @id_usu";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_usu", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id_usu;
 sqlconn.Open();
```

Mas no gridview? como faço???

Valeuu

Answer (score 0):

Galera bom dia.
Depois de 1 dia e algumas horas, procurando uma solução, consegui realizar da seguinte maneira:

No Sqldatasource, é criado um parâmetro que chamei de "queryParameter1", segue codigo:

```
 this.sqlDataSource1.ConnectionName = "String tpspoazsql01 onee";
        this.sqlDataSource1.Name = "sqlDataSource1";
        columnExpression1.ColumnName = "id_cliente_cobranca";
        table1.MetaSerializable = "0|0|125|240";
        table1.Name = "Cliente_enderecos_alter";
        columnExpression1.Table = table1;
        column1.Expression = columnExpression1;
        columnExpression2.ColumnName = "endereco";
        columnExpression2.Table = table1;
        column2.Expression = columnExpression2;
        columnExpression3.ColumnName = "numero";
        columnExpression3.Table = table1;
        column3.Expression = columnExpression3;
        columnExpression4.ColumnName = "bairro";
        columnExpression4.Table = table1;
        column4.Expression = columnExpression4;
        columnExpression5.ColumnName = "cidade";
        columnExpression5.Table = table1;
        column5.Expression = columnExpression5;
        columnExpression6.ColumnName = "estado";
        columnExpression6.Table = table1;
        column6.Expression = columnExpression6;
        columnExpression7.ColumnName = "cep";
        columnExpression7.Table = table1;
        column7.Expression = columnExpression7;
        selectQuery1.Columns.Add(column1);
        selectQuery1.Columns.Add(column2);
        selectQuery1.Columns.Add(column3);
        selectQuery1.Columns.Add(column4);
        selectQuery1.Columns.Add(column5);
        selectQuery1.Columns.Add(column6);
        selectQuery1.Columns.Add(column7);
        selectQuery1.FilterString = "[Cliente_enderecos_alter.id_cliente] = ?id";
        selectQuery1.Name = "Cliente_enderecos_alter";
```

> ```
>         queryParameter1.Name = "id";
>         queryParameter1.Type = typeof(int);
>         queryParameter1.Value = id_cliente;
> ```

```
        selectQuery1.Parameters.Add(queryParameter1);

        selectQuery1.Tables.Add(table1);
        this.sqlDataSource1.Queries.AddRange(new DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlQuery[] {
        selectQuery1});
        this.sqlDataSource1.ResultSchemaSerializable = resources.GetString("sqlDataSource1.ResultSchemaSerializable");
```

pois bem, feito isso, temos que atribuir um valor a nossa variavei "id_cliente" antes da inicialização dos componentes do form:

```
 public Manutenção_cliente(int id)
    {
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        id_cliente = id;

        InitializeComponent();

        // This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
        // Fill a SqlDataSource
        sqlDataSource1.Fill();
    }
```

Com isso, consegui realizar a consulta, não sei se é o método mais correto, se alguem puder comentar.

Valeu